# merging content types

Tags: nodes

I have used Drupal to build a helpdesk site, this site allows employees to submit a ticket to the IT department. Within the site is all of the computer assets that are managed. I want to be able to allow the IT technician to attach the ticket submitted to the asset that is in the system.  For example I have a printer with asset #12345 and someone submits a ticket saying it is working. The IT technician assigned to the ticket then competes the ticket and comments on what he/she did to fix it within the content type for the ticket. I need the comments from the  helpdesk ticket to be attached to asset #12345.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Assets and tickets are two Drupal content types? If two tickets are related to the same asset all comments from both tickets should be displayed in that asset page?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want your 'IT technician' user to be able to relate a 'ticket' (content type) to one (or more) 'assets' (also a content type).

You can use the [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module and provide a field on the 'ticket' content type that references to a node of the type 'assets'. The module has been integrated in Drupal 8 core, so no need to download the contributed module for that version.

This should be a good starting point in order to get the functionality that you want.

Comment: This Daily Dose of Drupal video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AcVz8Thxq48 explains the use of the Entity reference module. Though it is from a few years ago, it's still applicable here.